# Passing Argument to Grep to get specific output

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I am a newbie to Unix. Learning on my own.....I am writing a simple shell script to pull the Name of a dealer who was working a shift at the specified time where search takes place from multiple files within a directory.

Idea is I need to be able to pass Date of File e.g. 0310 or time in File e.g. 05 or time type from file AM or PM to pull specific dealer who was working at that time.

I am able to pull data using the following script

```
grep -i '05' 0310* | awk -F " " '{print $(01) , $(02) , $(05) , $(06)}' | grep -i am > Dealers_working_during_losses.txt
```

This gives me names of all dealers that are listed in file names 0310_Dealer_Analysis at 05 AM. Now I need to create a script so I can provide date, time & time type as an argument so a script can be used by anyone. Please advise how to proceed ? Since I am new bee , would appreciate simple solution so I can understand the logic rather than something complex....

Below is sample file data. I only need to pull data for Roulette dealer.

```
Hour AM/PM BlackJack_Dealer_FNAME LAST Roulette_Dealer_FNAME LAST Texas_Hold_EM_dealer_FNAME LAST

12:00:00 AM Izabela Parrish Marlene Mcpherson Madina Britton
01:00:00 AM Billy Jones Saima Mcdermott Summer-Louise Hammond
02:00:00 AM Summer-Louise Hammond Abigale Rich John-James Hayward
03:00:00 AM John-James Hayward Evalyn Howell Chyna Mercado
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide a sample of the source text?

Comment: Here is the file ......I only need to pull the Roulette dealer name.                                Hour AM/PM                                                                                  BlackJack_Dealer_FNAME LAST          Roulette_Dealer_FNAME LAST                                  
Texas_Hold_EM_dealer_FNAME LAST

12:00:00 AM Izabela Parrish Marlene Mcpherson Madina Britton
01:00:00 AM Billy Jones Saima Mcdermott Summer-Louise Hammond
02:00:00 AM Summer-Louise Hammond Abigale Rich John-James Hayward
03:00:00 AM John-James Hayward Evalyn Howell Chyna Mercado

Comment: Please post it in the question, in comments it's illegible :). [edit] the question and the format the text to code with the code tool `{}`.

Comment: added to question

Comment: The separator between names is a tab? In the text you posted they are all spaces, then we can't separate a person's name from the other. Can you post it with tabs or something?

Comment: yes separator is space which is why I used " " in awk command

Answer (score 1):

First let's clean up your existing script:

1) The `-i` arg to grep is for a lower case alphabetic comparison so it doesn't make sense to use it on numbers. So just get rid of the `-i` from `grep -i '05' 0310*`.

2) `" "` is the default FS value for awk so you don't need to specify that with `-F " "` - just get rid of that too.

3) The input field numbers don't need to be 2-digit, nor do they need to be wrapped in parentheses to delimit them so every `$(01)` etc. can just be `$1` etc.

4) You never need grep when you're using awk so this:

```
grep '05' 0310* |
awk '{print $1, $2, $5, $6}' |
grep -i am > Dealers_working_during_losses.txt
```

can be written as just:

```
awk '/05/{$0=$1 OFS $2 OFS $5 OFS $6; if (tolower($0) ~ /am/) print}' 0310* > Dealers_working_during_losses.txt
```

Now let's fix existing bugs:

5) `/05/` will find `05` **anywhere** in the record (as a minutes field for example) but you only want to find it at the start of the record as that's where the hour specification exists so change that to `/^05/`.

6) Similarly, just like `grep -i am` did, `tolower($0) ~ /am/` will find `am` anywhere in the record (in a persons name for example) but you only want to find it when it's the 2nd field in the record so change that to `tolower($2) == "am"`

We now have this command:

```
awk '/^05/{$0=$1 OFS $2 OFS $5 OFS $6; if (tolower($2) == "am") print}' 0310* > Dealers_working_during_losses.txt
```

but since we're only testing `$2` for am or pm, we don't need to build a whole new record ($0) first before testing then printing it and can instead do:

```
awk '/^05/{if (tolower($2) == "am") print $1, $2, $5, $6}' 0310* > Dealers_working_during_losses.txt
```

which we can write more idiomatically as:

```
awk '/^05/ && (tolower($2) == "am") {print $1, $2, $5, $6}' 0310* > Dealers_working_during_losses.txt
```

And now to how to create a shell script that accepts arguments for all of the values. That'd be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v time="$2" -v ampm="$3" '($0 ~ ("^"time)) && (tolower($2) == tolower(ampm)) {print $1, $2, $5, $6}' "$1"* > Dealers_working_during_losses.txt
```

which, assuming the above is stored in an executable file named `foo` that's in your `PATH`, you'd call as:

```
foo 0310 05 am
```

The only thing that I think is non-obvious above is that we had to use a different syntax for the time comparison when we went from testing a literal value (`^05`) to a string produced by concatenating the string `"^"` with the value of the variable `time` because use of a string in a regexp context requires us to use a [dynamic regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) which also means that the shortcut `/.../` for `$0 ~ /.../` that works in constant regexp comparisons cannot be used so we need to write the `$0 ~` part too.

Comment: Thx Ed...ill check this shortly !!!!